# JS / lodash - transform collection of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, javascript-objects

I'm looking for a Lodash / JS solution to transform collection (array of objects) from below structure:

```
let collection = [
    { category: "cat_1", banner: "banner_A", id: 1 },
    { category: "cat_1", banner: "banner_B", id: 2 },
    { category: "cat_2", banner: "banner_C", id: 3 },
    { category: "cat_2", banner: "banner_D", id: 4 },
    { category: "cat_2", banner: "banner_A", id: 5 },
    { category: "cat_3", banner: "banner_B", id: 6 }
];
```

into new structure:

```
let newCollection = [
    { 
      category: "cat_1", 
      banners: [
        { banner: "banner_A", id: 1 },
        { banner: "banner_B", id: 2 },
      ]
    },
    { 
      category: "cat_2", 
      banners: [
        { banner: "banner_C", id: 3 },
        { banner: "banner_D", id: 4 },
        { banner: "banner_A", id: 5 },
      ]
    },
    { 
      category: "cat_3", 
      banners: [
        { banner: "banner_B", id: 6 }
      ]
    }
]
```

Any idea? :)
CHeers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that first [**groups**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) the data by category and then [**maps**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) across each group to get the data in the required form. [**omit**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omit) is used to remove the category property from each item.

```
let result = _(collection)
    .groupBy('category')
    .map( (group, category) => ({
        category: category,
        banners: _.map(group, banner => _.omit(banner, 'category'))
    }))
    .value();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty straight-forward approach using plain JS.

It basically iterates over the collection and attempts to find an entry in the `newCollection` array with a matching `category` property. If it finds an entry, it pushes a new object to that entries' `banners` array, otherwise it pushes an entire new entry object to the `newCollection` array.

```js
var collection = [
    { category: "cat_1", banner: "banner_A", id: 1 },
    { category: "cat_1", banner: "banner_B", id: 2 },
    { category: "cat_2", banner: "banner_C", id: 3 },
    { category: "cat_2", banner: "banner_D", id: 4 },
    { category: "cat_2", banner: "banner_A", id: 5 },
    { category: "cat_3", banner: "banner_B", id: 6 }
];

var newCollection = [];
collection.forEach(item => {
  var entry = newCollection.find(x => x.category === item.category);
  var content = { banner: item.banner, id: item.id };

  if (!entry) {
    newCollection.push({
      category: item.category,
      banners: [content]
    });
  } else {
    entry.banners.push(content);
  }
});

console.log(newCollection);
```